# My member function designed to change a particular member data in a class doesn't actually change it

Tags: c++

I have started to write a program that makes a drink and calculates the price of it based on the different variables (toppings, size). However, when trying to write a function called setSize, designed to change the size of a particular drink, the bool value which keeps track of the size of the drink stays the same.

Here is my class:

```
class Boba {
    const double basePrice = 3.5;
    const double largeDrinkPrice = 1.;
    const double toppingPrice = 0.3;
private:
    string flavor;
    int toppings;
    bool isLarge;
    double price;
    void updatePrice();
public:
    Boba(string flavor1, int toppings1, bool isLarge1) {
        flavor = flavor1;
        toppings = toppings1;
        isLarge = isLarge1;
    }
    void setFlavor(string flavor);
    void setSize(bool isLarge);
    bool setToppings(int toppings);
    double getPrice();
    void printDrink();
};
```

I call this in my main function:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    std::cout << std::fixed << showpoint;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);

    Boba myDrink1("almond milk tea", 2, false);

    myDrink1.printDrink();

    cout << "Changing myDrink1 to a large size." << endl;
    myDrink1.setSize(true);
    myDrink1.printDrink();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My print drink function in case something goes wrong inside here:

```
void Boba::printDrink()
{
    cout << "Boba with flavor " << flavor << ", " << toppings << " toppings";
    if (isLarge)
        cout << ", size large";
    cout << ". $" << getPrice() << endl;
}

double Boba::getPrice()
{
    updatePrice();
    return price;
}
```

And this is where I am having problems, inside my setSize function and updatePrice function:

```
void Boba::updatePrice()
{
    if (isLarge) {
        price = largeDrinkPrice + (toppings * toppingPrice) + basePrice;
    }
    else {
        price = (toppings * toppingPrice) + basePrice;
    }
}

void Boba::setSize(bool isLarge)
{
    isLarge = true;
    updatePrice();
}
```

Edit: It seems that when it goes back to the update price function it turns false for isLarge.

Comment: in your `setSize` function you do `isLarge = true;`. It should be `isLarge = isLarge;`

Comment: `isLarge = isLarge;` is not going to work because you are setting the value the local variable `isLarge` to its current value. Maybe `this->isLarge = isLarge;`

Comment: @mattyx17 just tried this, it still doesn't print out the drink as a large size.

Comment: There's special name for what you're doing wrong, but I can't think of it. Basically, you're duplicating the name of a variable. That's won't work. You need to rename the parameter `isLarge` to something like `isLarge1` inside the `setSize()` like you do in the constructor.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you, this worked! I guess I had to explicity show which operator represented the member data of the calling object.

Comment: The member variable `isLarge` gets shadowed by the local variable of the same name. Related: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#C++)

Comment: While we're at it, why are you calling `updatePrice()` in `getPrice()`?  Getters should generally not mutate the object (and can then be marked `const`).

Comment: @PaulSanders If I don't call updatePrice() in getPrice, the first output for printDrink will return a price of 0.00. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Call it in your constructor, after you have set up all the member variables.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes this works, I can see how it is better to have it here rather than in a member function. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is really strange.

```
void Boba::setSize(bool isLarge) {
    isLarge = true; // you set the function parameter to true here, not the class member variable isLarge
    updatePrice();
}
```

use this-> to explicitly tell the compiler which variable to work with:

```
void Boba::setSize(bool isLarge) {
    this->isLarge = isLarge;
    updatePrice();
}
```

To avoid such mistakes one often uses custom prefixes for private variables not to mix them with function parameters, since they tend to have same names. _isLarge or m_isLarge (Qt style) for example. Then using this-> is not necessary and makes code cleaner and more readable.